# Newbie vector spaces question

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

So browsing the tasks our prof gave us to test our skills before the June finals, I've encountered something like this:

"Prove that the kernel and image are subspaces of the space V: $\ker(f) < V, \operatorname{im}(f) < V$, where $<$ means a subspace."

Is it just me or there's something wrong with the problem? I mean: I was rewriting the tasks from the blackboard by hand so I may have made a mistake but is a problem like this solvable or I messed up and should rather look for the task description from someone else? Cause for the time being, I don't see anything to prove here since we don't know what V is, right?

Comment: Apparently, $\,V\,$ is a vector (linear) space and $\,f:V\to V\,$ is a linear operator , and then the question makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. So what is the kernel of $f$? Indeed, it is $$\ker(f)=\{v\in V\mid f(v)=0_V\}$$ It is obvious that $\ker(f)\subseteq V$. Now take $a,b\in F$ the field associated to $V$, and let $v,w\in\ker(f)$. We have $$f(av+bw)=f(av)+f(bw)=af(v)+bf(w)= 0+0=0$$ So the subset $\ker(f)$ has the eligibility of being a subspace of $V$. Go the same way for another subset.

Comment: Hmm... I believe I get it, though I get stuck with $im(f)$. I know that $im(f)={v\in V: f(v)\in B}$ but is it enough to tell that it's a subset of V? Also, how does it prove it being a subspace?

Comment: @Straightfw: In fact, as we saw for $\ker(f)$, $0\in Im(f)$ cause $f$ is a linear transformation. Now if you take $v,w\in Im(f)$ and $a,b\in F$, you have $f(av'+bw')=af(v')+bf(w')=av+bw$ where $f(v')=v,f(w')=w$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It is good answer, Babak +1

Comment: I agree with @AdiDani $\;$ ;-) $\;+1$

Answer (score 3):

Implicit in the question is that $f:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$.  What you need to do in this problem is show that the kernel and image are not only subsets of $V$, but actually linear subspaces.  That is, you need to prove that they are closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot, will try to make something from it :)